# Reordering 2D array by value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = json_decode('[{"3609":1368486012},{"4286":1368546869},{"286":136848555}]',true);
```

What is the most efficient way to reorder by the value decending (timestamp)?

Comment: Sounds like `usort()` is your friend here.

Comment: Did you put any effort in this? Because first results of "order array by value" should easily lead you to a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reset` returns the value of first array element.

Code:

```
$array = json_decode('[{"3609":1368486012},{"4286":1368546869},{"286":136848555}]',true);

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return reset($b) - reset($a);
});

var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [4286]=>
    int(1368546869)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [3609]=>
    int(1368486012)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [286]=>
    int(136848555)
  }
}
```

Note: If you use PHP **5.2** ,

```
$array = json_decode('[{"3609":1368486012},{"4286":1368546869},{"286":136848555}]',true);

function mySort($a, $b) {
    return reset($b) - reset($a);
}
usort($array, 'mySort');

var_dump($array);
```

---

Oh, sorry
If you compare **float**,

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) 
        return 0;
    return ($a < $b) : 1 : -1;
}
```

Or

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
    return sprintf('%E', reset($b) - reset($a));
}
```

Comment: Oh... PHP on Codepad is version **5.2** ... very very very old... You should use Ideone ( **5.4** )

Comment: So i tried to apply this in other situations but it doesnt sort by decimal value properly.. 56.65, 56.55, 56.76. it only sorts integers.

Comment: Probably because (float)`-0.9`, ... (float)`0.1`, ... (float)`0.9` are casted to (int)`0`. You can avoid this using `sprintf`.